# Extracting SwiftUI view into new view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to extract a configured view into its own view struct, such that certain customizations can be applied? For example, I have this configured `Button` in a few places in my UI:

```swift
    Button(action: {}) {
        Text("Some Button Text")
            .font(.custom("SomeFont", size: 17.0))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .frame(height: 50.0)
    .foregroundColor(.black)
    .background(Color("user-profile-action-call1"))
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)))
    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20.0)
    .padding(.top, 33.0)
```

I’d like to be able to re-use it, specifying different button text and a different background color. Obviously one way would be to create a new `View` that takes a `String` and `Color` as parameters/properties, and use it like this:

```swift
    MyButton(title: "Some Button Text", color: Color("user-profile-action-call1"))
```

But that’s not as consistent with SwiftUI as:

```swift
    MyButton(title: "Some Button Text")
        .background(Color("user-profile-action-call1"))
```

Unfortunately, placing the background after the `.clipShape()` causes the padded area to be filled, not the clipped area.

There might be times when I want to change other aspects, too. But I’m not sure how to make a truly custom view like this.

Comment: You can create a new view as you mentioned or extend Button or create a new button style but I guess this isn’t the problem here but rather how to handle the modifiers?

Comment: Yeah for consistency with other SwiftUI configuration, it would be nice to be able to apply the modifiers in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 3):

[Grey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67683998/1326518) is a good one in terms of combining modifiers into a custom modifier, but I'd argue that a more idiomatic SwiftUI manner is to create a **button style**.

Custom button styles are structs that conform to the `ButtonStyle` protocol; to meet the protocol requirements, you need to supply a `makeBody` function that applies your styles to the button and returns a new view. Like any other views or modifiers, you can declare variables to initialise your struct with to make the style customisable.

In your case, I'd extract everything but the padding values:

```swift
struct FullWidthButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var backgroundColor: Color
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.custom("SomeFont", size: 17.0).bold())
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 50.0)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)))
    }
}
```

Note that because we're applying the font to a `Button` rather than directly to `Text`, the `.fontWeight` modifier won't work – but we should be able to apply `.bold()` to the font declaration itself (this requires Xcode 12.5 - in earlier versions you'd need to switch to `Font.custom...` to be able to chain font modifiers in this way).

You can then apply your style to any button, specifying whatever background colour you like:

```swift
Button(action: {}) { Text("Some Button Text") }
  .buttonStyle(FullWidthButtonStyle(backgroundColor: Color("user-profile-action-call1"))

Button(action: {}) { Text("Some other button text") }
  .buttonStyle(FullWidthButtonStyle(backgroundColor: .orange))
```

When it comes to ViewModifier vs ButtonStyle, I'd argue that the latter gives you a little bit extra semantic goodness: you only want to apply this style to buttons and nothing else, but view modifiers are a little bit too general to convey that.

Comment: Nice post but I'd say that ViewModifiers still "convey" their target via their type, so I don't think that's the key differentiator

Answer (score 0):

A custom view modifier can do this, but you have to keep in mind how SwiftUI creates views. Views are modified by view modifiers, which each return a **new** view. Because of this, the order in which you apply the modifiers in is important.

It wouldn't be possible to overwrite a view modifier (like its background color) after other view modifiers have been applied (not if you want the exact same results as just changing the original background).

You can create a new view modifier like this:

```
struct ButtonModifier: ViewModifier {
    var color:Color
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 50.0)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(color)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)))
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20.0)
            .padding(.top, 33.0)
    }
}

extension Button {
    func roundedWithBackground(_ color:Color) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ButtonModifier(color: color))
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to use your button elsewhere in your code with the following "more SwiftUI-like" syntax:

```
Button(action: {}) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.custom("SomeFont", size: 17.0))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
        }.roundedWithBackground(.red)
```

Obviously you can add more parameters to this view modifier as you wish, or if you wrapped some of the button parameters into their own view, it could be called like this:

```
MyButton(title: "Some Button Text")
    .roundedWithBackground(.red)
```